# Build many subproject that can be built independently and use common CMake variable by CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to give examples to some users of my project. The exmaple is to be used CMake. And It's like:

```
- top level
CMakeLists.txt
-- example A
A.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
-- example B
B.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
-- example C
C.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

I want to set some common CMake options in the top CMakeLists.txt, like:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++ -fexperimental-library")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lc++abi -fuse-ld=lld")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lc++abi -fuse-ld=lld")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -lc++abi -fuse-ld=lld")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

And I want that the example project can be built one time and the sub example can be built independently.

```
#A.cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

# Something to be added

project(A)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} A.cpp)
```

But I wish that I can do it without copy the common options into each CMakeLists.txt. I don't find a simple answer on StackOverflow or throughout Google. I think it should be a question may be met frequently in the fact. It's helpful to provide a tutorial even just a tutorial url.

Comment: You can place all the settings into a separate CMake file and use `include()` to read it from each example.

Comment: All of those options (except for the last 3) belong to a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-toolchain)... Furthermore in a toolchain file you should be using the variants of those variables with the `_INIT` suffix. As for the last 3: This is imho a decision that should be made on a per-target basis; you can use`target_compile_features(... PUBLIC cxx_std_20)`to have linking target inherit the property,e.g. if public headers of a lib contain C++20 features.Note that this doesn't result in the equivalent of`set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)`though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `add_subdirectory`? Would simplify things and should still meet your requirement?

```
option(MYPROJECT_BUILD_EXAMPLES "Build examples" OFF/ON)

...

if (MYPROJECT_BUILD_EXAMPLES)
  add_subdirectory(examples)
endif()
```